# How to use Checkbox to print worksheets as one file Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a list of 11 worksheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc.) in an Excel Workbook. I need to be able to select from that list, a set of sheets to print as one file. The names of the Sheets will not change.

So if I want to print all 11 at once, I would put:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4","Sheet5","Sheet6","Sheet7","Sheet8","Sheet9","Sheet10","Sheet11",).PrintOut
```

but instead of this, I want to choose any combination of the 11 to print out.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet3", "Sheet5", "Sheet7,"Sheet9","Sheet11").PrintOut
```

My goal has been to make the workbook user-friendly, so I have set up checkboxes that will unhide those specific sheets if the checkbox control cell is TRUE. Quick illustration:

```
If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("A1").Value = TRUE then
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = TRUE

'where ControlSheet Range A1 is the cell linked to the checkbox for that sheet.
```

I would like to be able to use those same checkboxes to select which sheets will print.

- To date, I have been able to print each sheet individually, but I want them to print all as one file.
- I have tried to set up a string name or variable array based on the control cell values, and reference that in my VBA  as my print array, but I get the "subscript out of range" error

My specific issue: I would like to generate a dynamic array in VBA based on cell values in a worksheet, and be able to use that array to print specific worksheets as one file.

Very open to other suggestions if you think maybe I am making this overly-complex for what I need. Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Are all `Checkbox`-es on the same sheet?

Comment: Yes they are all on the same sheet. One that will not be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just print the non-hidden sheets from that list of 11?

```
Sub PrintVisibleSheets()

    Dim arr, s, lst, sep

    arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
          "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet11")

    For Each s In arr
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s).Visible Then
            lst = lst & sep & s
            sep = "|" 'add separator after first pass
        End If
    Next s

    'any visible sheets?
    If Len(lst) > 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Split(lst, "|")).PrintOut

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean `s.Name`?

Comment: No -  `arr` is an array of strings, not an array of worksheet objects

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked it ^^', will be more careful next time.

Comment: This looks to have worked! Thank you so much! I will follow up soon with my complete code to share with others who need this solution

Answer (score 0):

Final Code below! Hope this can help someone else!

```
Sub PrintVisibleSheets()

If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C32").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

   End If

'next

If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C33").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
   End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C34").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True

   End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C35").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet4").Visible = True

    End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C36").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet5").Visible = True

   End If


'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C37").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet6").Visible = True

   End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C38").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet7").Visible = True

   End If

   'next




''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


 'Hide Sheets if False




   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C32").Value = True Then

   Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

   End If




'next

If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C33").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
   End If



'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C34").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = False

   End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C35").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet4").Visible = False


    End If

'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C36").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet5").Visible = False


   End If


'next

   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C37").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet6 ").Visible = False


   End If

'next


   If Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("C42").Value = False Then

   Sheets("Sheet7").Visible = False


   End If



   Dim arr, s, lst, sep

   arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7")

   For Each s In arr
       If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s).Visible Then
               lst = lst & sep & s
               sep = "|"
               End If

               Next s

               If Len(lst) > 0 Then


               Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600

                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Split(lst, "|")).PrintOut

               End If

End Sub
```